# How can I create a pivot table indexed on a column with duplicate entries that should be grouped by values of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['id1','id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id3'],
                       'key2': ['MIN','MIN','MAX','MAX','MIN','MIN','MAX','MIN'],
                       'key3': [0,1,0,1,0,2,1,0],
                       'value': [-1,-2,11,12,-4,0,9,-2]})

print(df)
  key1 key2  key3  value
0  id1  MIN     0     -1
1  id1  MIN     1     -2
2  id1  MAX     0     11
3  id1  MAX     1     12
4  id2  MIN     0     -4
5  id2  MIN     2      0
6  id2  MAX     1      9
7  id3  MIN     0     -2
```

Considering that:

- values in both `key1` and `key2` columns are not unique
- values of `key3` are irrelevant for our task (so we can group, aggregate or filter them anyway we like)

I want to create a pivot table where:

- the index has the unique values of `key1`
- the columns are the unique values of `key2`(we can assume those are only MAX and MIN)
- the values in the MAX column are the max of the values in the original dataframe for the given value of `key1` where `key2`=MAX
- the values in the MIN column are the min of the values in the original dataframe for the given value of `key1` where `key2`=MIN

So, for the given input, the output should be

```
      MIN  MAX 
id1    -2   12     
id2    -4    9
id3    -2  NaN
```

If I try to use the `pivot` function on the dataframe, I get a `ValueError` because `key1` has duplicate values

```
df.pivot(index='key1', columns='key2', values='value')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-eee9e613bc28> in <module>
----> 1 df.pivot(index='key1', columns='key2', values='value')
      2 # ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

and I can't use the `groupby` function because it would aggregate the MIN and MAX values together

```
print(df.groupby('key1').agg(MIN=('value', 'min'), MAX=('value', 'max')))
      MIN  MAX
key1          
id1    -2   12
id2    -4    9
id3    -2   -2
```

Is there a more elegant solution than creating two separate series (one for the MIN values and one for the MAX ones; in general, it would be a series for each distinct value in `key2`)?

```
min_series=df[df['key2'].eq('MIN')].groupby('key1').min()['value']
max_series=df[df['key2'].eq('MAX')].groupby('key1').max()['value']
print(pd.DataFrame({'MIN':min_series, 'MAX':max_series}))
     MIN   MAX
id1   -2  12.0
id2   -4   9.0
id3   -2   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of solving the problem by grouping the dataframe on `key1` and `key2` then for each subgroup aggregate the column `value` according to the aggregation function specified by `key2`:

```
d = {k: v.agg(k[1].lower()) for k, v in df.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])['value']}
frame = pd.Series(d).unstack()
```

---

```
>>> frame

      MAX  MIN
id1  12.0 -2.0
id2   9.0 -4.0
id3   NaN -2.0
```

Comment: nice one to use the name of key2 to create the wanted aggregate :)

Comment: Hey @Ben.T Thanks! your solution is also very clever..already upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way by creating a column for each value of key2 with `set_index` and `unstack`. Then you can use `groupby` and define in the `agg` what you want for each value of key2

```
res = (df.set_index('key2', append=True)
         ['value'].unstack()
         .groupby(df['key1'])
         .agg({'MAX':'max', 'MIN':'min'})
      )
print(res)
       MAX  MIN
key1           
id1   12.0 -2.0
id2    9.0 -4.0
id3    NaN -2.0
```